# Custom Compound View in XML with Default Layout Parameters

Tags: android, android-layout, viewgroup

Okay, so I'm trying to create a few reusable components. Basically, we have a compound layout that consists of:

-- Header
-- Description
-- (any number of controls)
-- Footer

So I have a custom ViewGroup that handles adding the header and footer automatically, with custom attributes for the text and other variables.

That all works great, but I'm trying to make it so that I can specify the control views (which have very specific layouts) in XML like so:

```
<com.mypackage.CustomLayout
    ///...
    >
    <com.mypackage.CustomControl
        //attributes
        />
    <com.mypackage.CustomControl2
        //attributes
        />
    <com.mypackage.CustomControl3
        //attributes
        />
</com.mypackage.CustomLayout>
```

For my custom controls, they all follow this general pattern:

**Example layout XML**

```
<merge
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
     //Attributes
    >
    <OtherView/>
    <OtherView/>
</merge>
```

**Corresponding Control View**

```
public class ControlView extends LinearLayout {
    public ControlView (Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public ControlView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
        parseAttributes(attrs);
    }

    public ControlView (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
        parseAttributes(attrs);
    }

    private void init () {
        LayoutInflater i = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        i.inflate(R.layout.example_layout, this);
        //Initialize subviews
    }
}
```

The problem is that the parameters in the merge tag are ignored, and I'm required to add `layout_width` and `layout_height` parameters for each custom control instead of it using the layout parameters defined in the merge tag.

If I try to set LayoutParams in the `init()` method, I still get a runtime exception saying that `layout_width` and `layout_height` attributes are required.

Is there a better way to do what I'm doing? I'd like to just provide preset `LayoutParams` for any instance of the custom control, regardless of what parameters (if any) are provided in the XML.